# MVC view freeze

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a strange issue. I've got create and edit view with it controller. Everything works fine, but (for example) if I don't enter a value, the validation **@Html.ValidationSummary(False)** returns the message error. The problem is when there is an error because the browser freeze and consume a lot of resources (memory) but after 4 or 5 minutes waiting, the view is rendered with the data and validation messages.

The server is: Windows 2003 Standard Edition, SQLServer 2008 Standard Edition, IIS6.0.
In development enviroment it's the same problem.
I'm using VS2010 SP1 with razor and MVC3. This issue happended in VS2008 SP1 with aspx and MVC2 too.

Someone knows what it's going on?

Regards.

---

Because it's reduce code maybe there is an error but the original it's fine. Of course all javascript and jquery calls exits

**Edit view**

```
@ModelType iSAM.Certificados

@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Edit"
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/CertificadosLayout.vbhtml"
End Code

@section Contenido
@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @<fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <br />

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Datos Generales</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.IDCertificado)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.IDCertificado, New With {.readonly = "readonly", .style = "width:90px; text-align:center", .class = "letraingreso"})
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:20px"></td>
                    <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.IDPoliza)
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.IDPoliza, Nothing, New With {.style = "width:200px; visibility:visible", .class = "letraingreso"})
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.IDCampaña)
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.IDCampaña, Nothing, New With {.style = "width:250px; visibility:visible", .class = "letraingreso"})
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:20px"></td>
                    <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.IDVigencia)
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.IDVigencia, Nothing, New With {.style = "width:183px; visibility:visible", .class = "letraingreso", .disabled = "disabled"})
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
        <br />

        <div id="tabs">
            @*Establece los tabs a ser creados*@
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>Asegurado</span></a></li>
            </ul>

            @*Asegurados*@
            <div id="fragment-1">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.IDAsegurado)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.IDAsegurado, New With {.readonly = "readonly", .style = "width:80px; text-align:center", .class = "letraingreso"})
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:20px"></td>
                        <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.IDTipoDocumentoAsegurado)
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.IDTipoDocumentoAsegurado, Nothing, New With {.style = "width:200px; visibility:visible", .class = "letraingreso"})
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:20px"></td>
                        <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.NumeroDocumentoAsegurado)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.NumeroDocumentoAsegurado, New With {.onkeyup = "if(this.value.match(/\D/))this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')", .class = "letraingreso", .style = "width:100px"})
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:20px"></td>
                        <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.FechaNacimientoAsegurado)
                            @Html.TextBox("FechaNacimientoAsegurado", Format(Model.FechaNacimientoAsegurado, "dd/MM/yyyy"), New With {.maxLength = "10", .onkeyup = "DateFormat(this, this.value, event, false, '3')", .onblur = "DateFormat(this, this.value, event, true, '3')", .style = "width:80px", .class = "letraingreso"})
                            <a href="#"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/spacer.gif")" class="imagenfecha" style="border:0" height="16px" width="20px" id="imgFechaNacimientoAsegurado" alt="" /></a>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                Calendar.setup(
                                {
                                    inputField: "FechaNacimientoAsegurado",
                                    ifFormat: "%d/%m/%Y",
                                    button: "imgFechaNacimientoAsegurado",
                                    align: "Tl",
                                    singleClick: true
                                });
                            </script>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.NombresAsegurado)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.NombresAsegurado, New With {.style = "text-transform:uppercase; width:270px", .class = "letraingreso"})
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:20px"></td>
                        <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.PrimerApellidoAsegurado)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.PrimerApellidoAsegurado, New With {.style = "text-transform:uppercase; width:182px", .class = "letraingreso"})
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:20px"></td>
                        <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.SegundoApellidoAsegurado)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.SegundoApellidoAsegurado, New With {.style = "text-transform:uppercase; width:182px", .class = "letraingreso"})
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.IDCiudadAsegurado)
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.IDCiudadAsegurado, Nothing, New With {.style = "width:180px; visibility:visible", .class = "letraingreso"})
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:15px"></td>
                        <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.DireccionDomicilioAsegurado)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.DireccionDomicilioAsegurado, New With {.style = "text-transform:uppercase; width:354px", .class = "letraingreso"})
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:20px"></td>
                        <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.CorreoElectronicoAsegurado)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.CorreoElectronicoAsegurado, New With {.class = "letraingreso", .style = "width:170px"})
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.IDGeneroAsegurado)
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.IDGeneroAsegurado, Nothing, New With {.style = "width:98px; visibility:visible", .class = "letraingreso"})
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:15px"></td>
                        <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.IDEstadoCivilAsegurado)
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.IDEstadoCivilAsegurado, Nothing, New With {.style = "width:120px; visibility:visible", .class = "letraingreso"})
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:15px"></td>
                        <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.TelefonoFijoAsegurado)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.TelefonoFijoAsegurado, New With {.class = "letraingreso", .style = "width:80px", .onkeydown = "javascript:return dFilter (event.keyCode, this, '###-##-####');"})
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:15px"></td>
                        <td style="border-width:0px; border-style:solid">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.TelefonoCelularAsegurado)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.TelefonoCelularAsegurado, New With {.class = "letraingreso", .style = "width:80px", .onkeydown = "javascript:return dFilter (event.keyCode, this, '###-##-####');"})
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Observaciones</legend>
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.Observaciones)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.Observaciones, New With {.class = "letraingreso", .style = "width:90%; text-transform:uppercase"})
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>

    @<div style="display:none; position:absolute; margin:auto; left:0; right:0; text-align:center" id="inprogress">
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <img id="inprogress_img" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/loading.gif")" alt="Procesando..." />
        <br />
        Por favor espere mientras su solicitud es procesada...
    </div>

    @<p>
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" id="cmdGuardar" onclick="return doSubmit()" />
    </p>

    @<div>
        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "ListarCertificadosVehiculos", "CertificadosLayout", New With {.area = ""}, New With {.class = "imgRegresar", .title = "Regresar"})
    </div>
End Using
End Section
```

**Class (remember it's a reduce code)**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class Certificados
Private varIDCertificado As Long
Private varIDPoliza As Long
Private varNumeroPoliza As Long
Private varIDCampaña As Long
Private varIDVigencia As Long

<DisplayName("Número de Certificado:")> _
Public Property IDCertificado() As Long
    Get
        Return varIDCertificado
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As Long)
        varIDCertificado = value
    End Set
End Property

<Required(ErrorMessage:="Debe seleccionar la poliza correspondinete")> _
<DisplayName("Número de Poliza:")> _
Public Property IDPoliza() As Long
    Get
        Return varIDPoliza
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As Long)
        varIDPoliza = value
    End Set
End Property

<DisplayName("Número de Poliza:")> _
Public Property NumeroPoliza() As Long
    Get
        Return varNumeroPoliza
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As Long)
        varNumeroPoliza = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

**Service (If return False the problem that I said appears)**

```
Public Function EditarCertificadoVehiculo(ByVal parCertificado As CERTIFICADO, ByVal parIDTarjetaCredito As String, ByVal parIDEstado As Long, _
                                          ByVal parLugarTrabajoAsegurado As LUGAR_DE_TRABAJO, ByVal parIDCiudadLugarTrabajo As Long, ByVal parLugarTrabajoPagador As LUGAR_DE_TRABAJO, ByVal parIDCiudadLugarTrabajoPagador As Long, _
                                          ByVal parAsegurado As ASEGURADO, ByVal parIDTipoDocumento As Long, ByVal parIDCiudadNacimiento As Long, ByVal parIDGenero As Long, ByVal parIDEstadoCivil As Long, _
                                          ByVal parPagador As ASEGURADO, ByVal parIDTipoDocumentoPagador As Long, ByVal parIDCiudadNacimientoPagador As Long, ByVal parIDGeneroPagador As Long, ByVal parIDEstadoCivilPagador As Long, _
                                          ByVal parConductor As CONDUCTOR, _
                                          ByVal parConcesionario As CONCESIONARIO, _
                                          ByVal parVehiculo As VEHICULO, ByVal parIDMarca As Long, ByVal parIDModelo As Long, ByVal parIDTipoPlaca As Long, ByVal parIDUsoVehiculo As Long, ByVal parIDColor As Long, _
                                          ByVal parArregloTasas As ArrayList, ByVal parArregloExtras(,) As String) As Boolean Implements IiSAMService.EditarCertificadoVehiculo

    If Not ValidarCertificadoVehiculo(parCertificado, parIDTarjetaCredito, parAsegurado, parLugarTrabajoAsegurado, parPagador, parLugarTrabajoPagador, parVehiculo, parIDTipoPlaca, parConcesionario, parArregloTasas, parIDEstado) Then
        Return False
    End If

    Try
        varRepositorio.EditarCertificadoVehiculo(parCertificado, parIDTarjetaCredito, parIDEstado, _
                                                 parLugarTrabajoAsegurado, parIDCiudadLugarTrabajo, parLugarTrabajoPagador, parIDCiudadLugarTrabajoPagador, _
                                                 parAsegurado, parIDTipoDocumento, parIDCiudadNacimiento, parIDGenero, parIDEstadoCivil, _
                                                 parPagador, parIDTipoDocumentoPagador, parIDCiudadNacimientoPagador, parIDGeneroPagador, parIDEstadoCivilPagador, _
                                                 parConductor, _
                                                 parConcesionario, _
                                                 parVehiculo, parIDMarca, parIDModelo, parIDTipoPlaca, parIDUsoVehiculo, parIDColor, _
                                                 parArregloTasas, parArregloExtras)
    Catch ex As Exception
        varDiccionarioValidacion.AddError("EditarCertificadoVehiculo", ex)
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Can you share some code?  Preferably your form and the action method it's submitting to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I tried with google chrome browser and the browser freeze for few minutes like IE8, but chrome do not crashed. So I could to see that a dropdownlist load thousands of records (maybe 100000-- my mistake).

This is the corrected line:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form("NombreLugarTrabajoAsegurado")) Then
            varListado = New SelectList(varServicio.ListarLugaresTrabajoPorNombre("NO DEFINIDO", True, True), "ID_LUGAR_TRABAJO", "NOMBRE_LUGAR_TRABAJO")
        Else
            varListado = New SelectList(varServicio.ListarLugaresTrabajoPorNombre(Request.Form("NombreLugarTrabajoAsegurado"), True, True), "ID_LUGAR_TRABAJO", "NOMBRE_LUGAR_TRABAJO", Request.Form("IDLugarTrabajoAsegurado"))
        End If
        ViewData("IDLugarTrabajoAsegurado") = varListado
```

Maybe IE team needs to fix this to prevent crashes.
I hope this helps someone else.